# Is this partial derivative correct

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

For

$$
a^{2} = \sigma(w^2 a^{1}+b^2) = \sigma(z^2)\\
\\ \text{where} \;
z^l =w^l a^{l-1} +b^l
$$
If we write the derivate

$$
{\frac{\partial a^{l} }{\partial w^{l}} = \frac{\partial \sigma (z^{l}) }{\partial w^{l}} = \sigma' (z^{l}) \quad \rightarrow  ( {a})} \\
$$
Then is the below proper
$$ 
\frac{\partial(a^2)}{\partial(a^1)} = \frac{\partial(\sigma(w^2 a^{1}+b^2))}{\partial(a^1)} =  w^2.\sigma'(a^1)  \; \rightarrow  ( {b})\\ \\
$$

Comment: Superscripts are indices I suppose? In the last expression the argument of $\sigma$ should not change.

Comment: yes these are indices

Comment: full context here https://itisexplained.com/html/NN/ml/5_codingneuralnetwork/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $a^2$ and $a^1$ are distinct variables, then you are mostly correct.  It should be $$\frac{\partial a^2}{\partial a^1} = w^2\sigma'(w^2 a^1 + b^2) $$ rather than $w^2\sigma'(a^1)$.